# How do I make use of GraphQL Apollo cache for offline support?

Tags: caching, graphql, apollo

I'm building an Apollo app that needs to have offline support.

I understand that Apollo allows us to have direct control to the cache using `apollo-cache-inmemory`, and with method like `writeQuery` we are able to mutate the cache data without changing the data on the server.

What's the best approach to sync local cache data with the server, let's say, on a scenario where the app could go offline for a period of time?

Answer (score 3):

AWS AppSync will handle this for you and has an Apollo plug in:

```
yarn add aws-appsync
yarn add aws-appsync-react
```

This will perform offline caching and automatic synchronization as well as conflict resolution. You can also control Optimistic UI using the AppSync plugin and Apollo: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app-react.html#offline-settings

Comment: thanks. Does it mean I'll have to use AWS db as data source for this to work?

Comment: @tropicalfish  AppSync supports DynamoDB, Amazon Elasticsearch and AWS Lambda. If you'd like to use another DB, for example MySQL, you can connect to it using the Lambda data source. Offline functionality will work just the same.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see this one? Maybe it can help....
https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/announcing-apollo-cache-persist-cb05aec16325

Comment: That link seems to be web specific